# Python command line argument using sys.argv

Tags: python

After the responses below, I understand the difference between

`dir_path = sys.argv[1`] And  `dir_path = sys.argv[1:]`

I am trying to understand why the code is failing. What I am trying to do is following:

- read the target directory from command line
- run through all the subdirectories in target directory and do untar operation on all the files within the sub-directories (not written by me)
- do some post processing on the unzipped files

Here is the code snippet. It throws an error when it gets to for loop

```
if __name__ == '__main__':

dir_path = sys.argv[1:]

total = untar(sys.argv[1:])
print total

for radar_list in os.listdir(dir_path):
     #do some post-processing

def untar(paths):
    total = 0
    for path in paths:
        if os.path.isdir(path):
            try:
                dir_list = os.listdir(path)
            except:
                pass
            else:
                total += untar(os.path.join(path, new) for new in dir_list)
        elif os.path.isfile(path):
            try:
                tarfile.open(path).extractall(os.path.dirname(path))
            except:
                pass
            else:
                total += 1
    return total
```

Error is:

```
Traceback (most recent call last):
  File "post_p.py", line 304, in <module>
    for issue_list in os.listdir(dir_path):
TypeError: coercing to Unicode: need string or buffer, list found
```

Comment: https://docs.python.org/2/tutorial/introduction.html#lists

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Look at it this way. When you pass arguments using `sys.argv` you pass them in a list form. So what you are doing pretty much is just accessing a list element or slicing the list.

A simple example is:

```
>>> l = [1,2,3,4,5]
>>> l[1]
2
>>> l[1:]
[2, 3, 4, 5]
```

So when you are running your program I'm assuming you are doing

```
python program.py "c\path\2somewhere",   1,        2  
#This  argv[0]       argv[1]           argv[2]   argv[3]
```

If you look at how you run the program with the example context in mind, i think you can see the difference `:` makes

Comment: Thanks for the response. Can you check edited post above. I have posted the full code snippet of what I am trying to do, but it is throwing an error.

Comment: You are passing a list in `for radar_list in os.listdir(dir_path):` .Since you are declaring `dir_path = sys.argv[1:]` notice the `[1:]` notation. You need a string. If you had a `print` statement for `dir_path` you can see its value. its going to be something like ["path",x,y,etc]. You only need the path.

Comment: Glad I could help. I had a similar problem understating it when i was learning Python as well :)

Answer (score 1):

When you pass `python myprog.py arg1 arg2 arg3` . It is passed as a list.

Where:

```
[0] --> path/to/your/program.py
[1] --> arg1
[2] --> arg2
[3] --> arg3
```

`sys.argv[1]` will give you `arg1`

`sys.argv[1:]` will give you `[arg1, arg2, arg3]`

Comment: except that it wont.  `[1:]` excludes the first argument

Comment: the first argument is the `myprog.py` at the zero-th index (first element) . Please check

Answer (score 0):

The 1st one is a string and the 2nd one is a list containing all arguments except the 1st one.

Answer (score 0):

if there is only one argument there is no difference, in general [1:] will select all elements of an array apart from the very first one:

```
A = [0, 1, 2]  
print A[1]  
>>>  1  
print A[1:]  
>>>> [1, 2]
```